# Elm merge two different records into one large one

Tags: merge, record, elm

In Elm , is it possible to do something like this.

REPL

```
> a = {d = 4 , y = 5}
{ d = 4, y = 5 }
    : { d : number, y : number1 }
> b = {b = 4,n=1}
{ b = 4, n = 1 }
    : { b : number, n : number1 }
> c = {a | b | g=5}
```

I want c to contain all members of a and of b without individually naming them.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Elm does not support changing the shape of a record using the record update syntax ([though it was possible before Elm 0.19](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/9f1bbb558095d81edba5796099fee9981eac255a/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#stricter-record-update-syntax)), and there is nothing similar to the [… spread syntax in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

You will need to use explicit syntax to copy each field into a new record.

```
type alias One =
    { d : Int, y : Int }


type alias Two =
    { b : Int, n : Int }


type alias Three =
    { d : Int, y : Int, b : Int, n : Int, g : Int }


merge : One -> Two -> Three
merge { d, y } { b, n } =
    { d = d, y = y, b = b, n = n, g = 5 }
```